# Should I keep the variable that equals $q.defer() to have lexical scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my application, I am setting `var def = $q.defer();` and using the `def.resolve(myFunction)`. I am confused whether I should keep def local or just make it a global variable since it will always equal `$q.defer()`. Any suggestions? I am always hesitant to make something a global variable so sorry if it may sound like a dumb question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object (which you are assigning to `def`) returned by `$q.defer()` represents a single deferred task, so `def` should remain local. You will want to call `$q.defer()` and assign the resulting object to a variable for each individual deferred task. As Tom said in his answer, subsequent calls to `def.resolve()` for the same instance of `def` will return the same value as the initial resolution, which may be useful in some cases (e.g. a value that needs to be retrieved from the server, but only needs to be retrieved once and can be cached, but you don't know when the first attempt to retrieve it might be because it depends on user behavior).

Comment: Thanks @jbhannah! Appreciate the nice concise answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

After you `resolve` once, that is going to be the response for anything referencing that `$q` instance.

Here is an example, which, in the controller, will log *"something else"* twice because it was the first resolution of your global `$q` object (resolves in 200ms instead of 400ms.  If you were to change the length that `factory1.doSomething()` runs for, it would then be the result):

[Here](http://jsbin.com/zizijenuri/edit?js,console) is a jsBin.

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .factory('factory1', factory1)
  .factory('factory2', factory2)
  .factory('qfactory', qfactory)
  .controller('controllerSomething', controllerSomething);

function controllerSomething(factory1, factory2) {
  factory1.doSomething().then(function(result) {
    console.log(result); // something else
  });

  factory2.doSomething().then(function(result) {
    console.log(result); // something else
  });
}

function factory1(qfactory) {
  return {
    doSomething: function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        qfactory.getQ().resolve('something');
      }, 400);

      return qfactory.getQ().promise;
    }
  };
}

function factory2(qfactory) {
  return {
    doSomething: function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        qfactory.getQ().resolve('something else');
      }, 200);

      return qfactory.getQ().promise;
    }
  };
}

function qfactory($q) {
  var q = $q.defer();

  return {
    getQ: function() {
      return q;
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tom appreciate the example!